# Creating Statistical Process Control Charts in Website

Tags: jquery, html, charts

I'm currently looking into a method of creating process control charts within a website using data gathered from a database query in Excel (Wonderware Historian add-on).

I already have a method for one set of charts that moves data from Excel to Minitab and then saves the charts as jpegs for publishing, but I feel there may be a better way using the power of HTML and JS.

Does anybody know the best charting framework to use for these kinds of graphs?  I've been looking at Highcharts, but I don't understand how I can implement auto-generating control limits or even where to start to create the kind of chart I need.  Struggling to find related info on the web too.

Has anybody got experience creating these already?  If somebody can point me in the right direction that would be excellent.  I'm also a new start on JS, so don't know a great deal about it.

Comment: I understand this is an old thread but may I know the reason why would you want to the power of HTML and JS? What's the rationale behind it?

Comment: Hi.  This was to display process data at work and my resources were very limited at the time.  I've now got access to a Tableau server which allows me to display the charts in many ways to people all over the business.